Lower bound for variance of sum of with functions containing gaussian random vectors.
in my current research i am stuck with the following problem and search for nice lower bounds:
Assume that the n-dimensional random $X_j$ is normal distributed, i.e. $X_j \sim N(0,\Sigma_j)$ where $\Sigma_j\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a positive definite matrix and $\mathbb{E}[(X_j - \mathbb{E}[X_j])^T(X_{j'} - \mathbb{E}[X_{j'}])] = \sigma_j^2 \delta_{j=j'}$ for some $\sigma_j>0.$ What can be said about the quantity $\mathbb{E}[\sum_j f_j(X_j)]^2$ where $f_j:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are square integrable functions with $\mathbb{E}[f_j(X_j)]=0.$ To be more precise, is it possible to derive $\mathbb{E}[\sum_j f_j(X_j)]^2 \geq c \sum_{j=1}^p \mathbb{E}[f_j(X_j)^2]$ for some $c>0$?
For example: The claim is trivial if $X_j$ is independent across $j$, since then $\mathbb{E}[\sum_j f_j(X_j)]^2= \sum_j \mathbb{E}[f_j(X_j)^2] + \sum_{j\neq j'} \mathbb{E}[f_j(X_j)f_{j'}(X_{j'})]= \sum_j \mathbb{E}[f_j(X_j)^2] + \sum_{j\neq j'} \mathbb{E}[f_j(X_j)]\mathbb{E}[f_{j'}(X_{j'})] =\sum_j \mathbb{E}[f_j(X_j)^2] + 0.$

Does your condition $\mathbb{E}[f_j(X_j)] = 0$ not already imply that the left-hand-side of the inequality is $0$?

No, the square is within the expectation.
